# sqlite3 missing in Android TV?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-tv, nexus-player

I've been trying to run some sqlite3 commands once shelled into a Nexus Player via adb and it can't find the `sqlite3` command.

Is this not available on Android TV builds? Is there a location to pull this from that would work on it?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this by pushing a sqlite3 binary to the nexus player.
Keep in mind: the Nexus Player by ASUS is a x86 device, so you should get a x86 binary.

Push by

`adb push X:\sqlite3 /data/local/tmp`

After pushing, navigate to the path you've pushed the binary to

`adb shell
cd /data/tmp/local`

When in the appropiate directory, set the permissions

`chmod +x ./sqlite3`

Then you can run it by

`./sqlite3 <path-to-your-sqlite-db>`